# DataGridView - How to get the DataPropertyName of the currentlt selected

Tags: .net, vb.net, datagridview

Hi there I have pretty simple piece of code the intention of which is to provide default values for new records entered via a DataGridView.  I am using the DefaultValuesNeeded event to provide the default information of the record as in the code below:

```
     Private Sub SetGridDefaults()
    Dim colName As String
    Dim col As DataGridViewColumn
    If Not _protected Then
        With uxGrid
            col = .Columns(.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex)
            colName = col.DataPropertyName
            Select Case colName
                Case "DATASOURCEID"
                    uxGrid.CurrentCell.Value = _dataSourceID
            End Select
        End With
    End If
End Sub
```

Unfortunately it appears that the 'CurrentCell' property is not populated at this point and the code errors with:

'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'

How do I obtain the datapropertyname in order to use it within the context of my code?

Kind Regards
Paul J.

Comment: `the 'CurrentCell' property is not populated at this point` and where is "this point" - the DefaultValuesNeeded event?  If so, that event fires for the *row*.  The [MSDN example](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.defaultvaluesneeded(v=vs.110).aspx) shows how to use the event args to set values.  You can also specify default values as part of the DefaultCellStyle property for each row

Comment: I am attempting to provide a generic sub-routine, setting default values, some of which are common to multiple forms.  The forms involved inherit from a base class which contains the aforementioned sub.

Comment: Default values have nothing to do with `DataGridView.CurrentCell`. For generic sub-routine you should provide information of `DataGridView.Cell` as parameter. Or Provide full `DataGridViewRow` where sub-routine will fill it with default values.